# How do I sum all numbers from output of jq

Tags: jq

I have this command that I would like to sum all the numbers from the output.

The command looks like this

```
$(hadoop fs -ls -R /reports/dt=2018-08-27 | grep _stats.json | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs hadoop fs -cat | jq '.duration')
```

So it's going to list all the folders in `/reports/dt=2018-08-27` and get only `_stats.json` and pass that through `jq` from `hadoop -cat` and get only `.duration` from the json. Which in the end I get the result like this.

```
1211789 1211789 373585 495379 1211789
```

But I would like the command to sum all those numbers together to become `4504331`

Comment: I suspect that you're running `echo $val` rather than `echo "$val"` in printing your result -- otherwise, I'd expect newlines instead of spaces between the values, as `jq` output is newline-separated unless explicit action is taken to change this behavior (but an `echo` with an unquoted argument *is* such specific action, as described in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)).

Comment: @glennjackman, ...hmm. Almost a shame this was tagged as a bash question (since this *is* duplicative in bash) rather than a jq question (since there's a distinct and useful answer specific to that toolchain).

Comment: Agreed. I reopened and edited tags accordingly

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another option (and one that works even if not all your durations are integers) is to make your `jq` code do the work:

```
sample_data='{"duration": 1211789}
{"duration": 1211789}
{"duration": 373585}
{"duration": 495379}
{"duration": 1211789}'

jq -n '[inputs | .duration] | reduce .[] as $num (0; .+$num)' <<<"$sample_data"
```

...properly emits as output:

```
4504331
```

Replace the `<<<"$sample_data"` with a pipeline on stdin as desired.

Comment: nice but a bit overcomplicated, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771918/501765)

Answer (score 58):

the simplest solution is the `add` filter:

```
jq '[.duration] | add'
```

the `[` brackets `]` are needed around the value to sum because `add` sums the values of an *array*, not a stream. (for stream summation, you would need a more sophisticated solution, e.g. using `reduce`, as detailed in other answers.)

---

depending on the exact format of the input, you may need some preprocessing to get this right.

e.g. for the sample input in [Charles Duffy’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52065738/501765) either

- use `inputs`  (note that `-n` is needed to avoid jq swallowing the first line of input):

  ```
  jq -n '[inputs.duration] | add' <<< "$sample_data"
  ```
- or slurp (`-s`) and iterate (`.[]`) / map:

  ```
  jq -s '[.[].duration] | add' <<< "$sample_data"
  jq -s 'map(.duration) | add' <<< "$sample_data"
  ```

Comment: For me `jq '[.duration] | add' <<< "$sample_data" ` does not produce the sum of values but the outputs the list of numbers.

Comment: @Romain I assume you came from [Charles Duffy’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52065738/501765); I am going to update mine with caveats for that kind of input

Comment: Just a sidenote: Giving an empty array to `add` produces `null`, not `0`, which might mess up following operations.

Comment: I would write the last variant as `jq -s 'map(.duration) | add' <<< "$sample_data"` which is a bit more intuitive

Answer (score 16):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ ... | awk '{sum+=$0} END{print sum}'

4504331
```

Answer (score 15):

You can just use `add` now.

```
jq '.duration | add'
```

Comment: Did not work for me :(
It throws the following error:
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over number (362425)

Comment: @JeraldSabuM wrap your values with an array

Answer (score 3):

For clarity and generality, it might be worthwhile defining `sigma(s)` to add a stream of numbers:

```
... | jq -n '
  def sigma(s): reduce s as $x(0;.+$x); 
  sigma(inputs | .duration)'
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 2):

From a combination of other answers.

```sh
$ jq -n '[inputs | .duration] | add' <<< "$sample_data"

# 4504331
```

I had to format the values in an array `[inputs | .duration]` before summing values with `add`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `for` loop.

```
total=0
for num in $(hadoop fs -ls -R /reports/dt=2018-08-27 | grep _stats.json | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs hadoop fs -cat | jq '.duration')
do
    ((total += num))
done
echo $total
```

Comment: You really shouldn't write loops like that: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29 Note that most of that pipeline is redundant as well

Comment: @DTSCode Those pitfalls are all about filenames, which could contain spaces. This pipeline only produces numbers, there shouldn't be a problem. I agree that the pipeline could be improved, but it wasn't necessary to address the main question.

Comment: I'm well aware of what the pitfall is for. Like I said previously, my point is that you shouldn't write for loops in that manner. There is always a better solution, bash or otherwise.

Comment: Why shouldn't I write a for loop like this when I know I'm just looping over numbers? There's no need to write this using `while read -r num ...`

Comment: And other than combining `grep` and `awk`, I'm not sure what's redundant. Note that I'm not familiar with the `hadoop` command, so there could be ways to simplify those parts that I don't know.